# Boost search results in Lucene via the presence of a field value

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, kentico

I am using Lucene.net via Kentico.  I am trying to boost results that have a particular value in a field. For example:

`myfield:"myvalue"^2`

Unfortunately this is treated as a search term and alters the scores (via `tf` and `idf` etc) anyway.

Is there a way of boosting a result based on the presence of a value, but not including that value as a search term?

**update**

So I want to boost the score of records that contain that value in that field only, its not a search value in any way.

Failing that, as I am actually using two indexes, could I apply a boost to a particular index?  For example, items from in index-1 have a slightly higher score overall than those from index-2

Answer (score 0):

If you added this field in the "Search Condition" then behind the scenes it adds a "+" to the value, so the lucene is rendering:

```
+(myfield:"myvalue"^2)
```

Which then requires the field.

I believe (you will have to test) if you add a Smart Search Filter, set the value to `myfield:"myValue"^2` and then set the "Filter is conditional" to false, this should properly add in your field to the lucene to boost, then just wrap the filter with some `<div style="display:none"></div>` to hide it.

Point that to your Results and see if it does the trick!

Comment: I am actually do this code in the back-end, so I can control the exact syntax thats produced.  The problem is that even by including ```myfield:"myvalue"``` (with no boost), its still changing the scoring.  Its saying is myvalue rare in that column, if so, up its score. I really just want to boost that records score because it has that value over records that don't by the boost value specified.

Comment: You can do multiple boosting, set primary search as boost 2 then that as boost 0.5, and adjust till it does what you want.

Comment: are you saying there isn't actually a way of doing what I need? Boosting a result by the presence of a value, but scoring that value as it would a search value?